# Discovering free ports

Tags: tcp, erlang

I wrote an server application in erlang and a client in C#. They communicate through 3 TCP ports. Port numbers are hardcoded. Now I'd like to do this dynamically. This is my first time doing network programming, so please pardon my inability to use proper terminology :-D

What I would like to do is make a supervisor which would accept a TCP connection from a client on a previously known port (say, 10000, or whatever), then find 3 free ports, start a server application on those 3 ports and tell the client those port numbers so client can connect to the server.

My particular problem is: how do I find 3 ports which are not in use? (clarification: which module:fun() to use to find a free port?)

My general problem is: I'm sure this kind of stuff (one server allocating ports and redirecting clients) is quite common network programming problem and there should be a bunch of (erlang-specific or general) resources about this, but I just don't have the terminology to google it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the Erlang documentation [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#listen-2), if the Port argument to the gen_tcp:listen/2 function is 0, then the OS will assign any available port to the socket. The latter can then be retreived using inet:port/1 .

You can therefore do something like this :

```
{ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(0, [Options]),
Port = inet:port(Listen).
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Then I just communicate those back to the supervisor who relay those to the client. Nice, thanks!

Comment: Elixir version: `{:ok, listen} = :gen_tcp.listen(0, []); {:ok, port} = :inet.port(listen); port`

Answer (score 3):

just in case you didn't know that - you dont have to allocate new ports for each client, it's perfectly fine to have all clients to connect to same ports

UPDATE:

if there is a reason to allocate new ports for incoming clients then it's far beyond your first "introduction to network programming" program.

separate ports could mean you want to completely isolate environments of different groups of clients. it's comparable to providing completely different IP addresses to connect to. if you want to write a simple ping-pong program - you don't need it. and i honestly believe you will never need to use such solution in your whole life - that's how incredibly rarely it is.

regarding cpu/ports overhead - allocating ports and starting a server that listens to that port is already far bigger overhead than accepting clients on same port.

Comment: Yeah, but supervisor will spawn a brand new server for each client. But, you are right, I could use only 3 ports in this situation also... Hm. What's better: to have each server allocate 3 distinct ports (port usage overhead), or to have only 3 global ports and then have a dedicated server redirect traffic from each client to it's respective server (CPU overhead)?

Comment: i have a feeling you misunderstood a tutorial about network programming at some point. i'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I would like to isolate groups of clients. I'm doing a simulator server. Currently my app is one instance of a simulator talking to one client, and I'd like to write a server which assigns a brand new simulator for each client, so several clients can run several distinct isolated simulators (only thing shared would be the entry point where the client asks for a new simualtor). If one simulator goes belly up, I don't want it to take other simulators underwater. That's why I was thinking separate port triplet for each client.

Comment: what stops you from running simulator for each accepted client on one port?

Comment: Again, isolation. There are 3 things a client can do with a simulator: GET a parameter, SET a parameter and do an ACTION. GET gen_server is just simply relaying state variables from server to client and should be quite stable, but SET and ACTION servers have a potential for crashing since they do some real action. So I'd like to isolate each server on it's own port, so if one of those 3 gen_servers crashes, it doesn't take the other two with him. Am I doing this right or am I taking this isolation thing to far? (I'm an erlang / network programming noob, so have mercy :-D)

Comment: not trying to offend or anything, i just have feeling that you're overcomplicating your solution. what about this kind of server loop: http://www.pastie.org/2110927. you spawn this loop for every client and then as you get TCP packets you send corresponding messages to spawned process to handle those packets. such loop will be enough level of isolation you would need in 99% of cases, it will maintain isolated State and if it crashes - it will not affect any other client.

Comment: Offend? Man, I'm trying to learn here, feel free to say whatever you wish ;-) You are right, I overcomplicated it. I somehow decided that now that I'm using gen_server, I mustn't use spawn because that's too low level. You are right, I'll have just one gen_server receiving packets on one port and then spawning a new process or each packet. But, it still makes sense to have dedicated port for each simulator instance, right? Or should I also use just one port and then have a gen_server redirect communication to the right simulator instance?

Comment: it's hard to answer your question because i don't know what is the cost of spawning new instance of simulator and i don't know if your simulator can work with many clients by just using client state(or by using client state + simulator state pair for each client). these are things you will have to figure out yourself. also you have to spawn loop not for each packet but for each *accept* - that's when tcp connection was opened between client and server. have a look at this very simple tcp server implementation: http://20bits.com/articles/erlang-a-generalized-tcp-server/ hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid commonly known ports, ftp, http, smtp etc,  But I don't think there is any master list of which ports other software uses that you should avoid.  I think your best bet is to come up with a range of ports you want to use.  Check at runtime if anybody else answers ( is using the ports ) on the numbers you choose dynamically, if not issue it to the client.

Comment: "Check at runtime if anybody else answers ( is using the ports ) on the numbers you choose dynamically" - well, yes. But I don't know how to do that :-D That's exactly what I asked. I simply cannot google it out. So, how to I find out if anybody is using a port?

Comment: There actually is a master list of ports used by software: http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers